# ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MyTable_SomeCol]

Tags: t-sql

If I script a table with a foreign key, it looks like this:

```
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MyTable_SomeCol] FOREIGN KEY([SomeCol])
REFERENCES [dbo].[MyOtherTable] ([SomeCol])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MyTable_SomeCol]
GO
```

What is the second part for (`ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MyTable_SomeCol]`)?

Comment: I don't see the second statement when I script a table with a foreign key (SQL Server 2008 R2). Are you sure the first one does not contain **`WITH NOCHECK`** instead of `WITH CHECK`?

Comment: Yep it is WITH NOCHECK. Now its functionality is more clear to me. Thank you all!

Answer (score 20):

It's an artifact of the way that the constraint is scripted - although it's unnecessary to specify these options (since they're the defaults for new constraints), the same generator can also generate `NOCHECK` options in exactly the same manner.

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) for `ALTER TABLE` indicates two distinct uses of `CHECK`/`NOCHECK`:

> `WITH CHECK | WITH NOCHECK`
>
> Specifies whether the data in the table is or is not validated against a newly added or re-enabled `FOREIGN KEY` or `CHECK` constraint. If not specified, `WITH CHECK` is assumed for new constraints, and `WITH NOCHECK` is assumed for re-enabled constraints.

And:

> `{ CHECK | NOCHECK } CONSTRAINT`
>
> Specifies that constraint_name is enabled or disabled.

So one option is saying "check the current contents of the table", the other is saying "Validate new data as it is added".

Answer (score -1):

This is a way of implementing [referential integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_Integrity) for your tables.